# Can't read all files properly from StorageFile in Windows 8 metro application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, async-await

I'm developing a simple application in Windows 8 metro applications and I m trying to retrieve files from PicturesLibrary, the code I put is the following :

```
public async void Initialize()
{
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> storageFiles = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFilesAsync();              
    foreach (var storageFile in storageFiles)
    {   
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        FileRandomAccessStream stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = bitmapImage;
        Images.Add(image);
    }
}
```

then I show these images using their ImageSource.
The problem that I am meeting is that sometimes it shows them all, somethimes one
or two , sometimes it deosn't show any image, I don't understand if this is because of the awaitable method GetFileAsync() or other things I may be missing.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why not try the NON-async method and see if you consistently get all files?

Comment: @jberger - no such API available, Metro has lots of async-only like Silverlight did before.

Comment: I'm not familiar with async/await yet, but it appears `StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync()` returns an `IAsyncOperation<IReadOnlyList>` which in turn has a `Completed` event..

Comment: What exactly happens? Are the images in `storageFiles`, but they are not shown? Or are they missing from `storageFiles`? Also, you should not write `async void` methods if you don't have to.

Comment: Hows your memory usage? Kind of looks like you are reading all images into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess it's just a timing issue, but doing a breakpoint or trace point in the foreach would tell for sure.

Try changing this to return Task and then await it in the caller of you can

Comment: thanks @James, Yeah I think It's a timing issue as you said, I tried some break points within that foreach loop and it worked better , but as I am not really familiar with async operations I am not really sure how implement your solution, I will be very thankful if you give me some links for that, thanks again .

Comment: Just change the void to Task in the method declaration then have the caller await or .Wait() depending on whether the caller could/should be async as well

Comment: My guess would be that the view that uses Images is getting the contents of Images while this function is still putting bitmaps into Images. That would be OK, and the view could update as images were added, if Images was a  ObservableCollection<>.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will be this line.

```
FileRandomAccessStream stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
```

Awaiting inside a loop is likely going to give you some odd scope issues.
The first thing I would try is switching the first two lines of this loop around.

```
FileRandomAccessStream stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
```

It could be that the `bitmapImage` reference is being repointed on you. If this doesn't help though, you might need to look at the `.ContinueWith` method.

```
storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read).ContinueWith(task => {
  FileRandomAccessStream stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)task.Result;
  BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
  bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
  Image image = new Image();
  image.Source = bitmapImage;
  Images.Add(image);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Chris , I tried to switch those two lines but it didn't work, even there is no definition for .ContinueWith() method. thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution for this thanks to you guys , I had to rearrange the code little bit,

```
public async Task Initialize()
        {   
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> storageFiles = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFilesAsync();              
            foreach (var storageFile in storageFiles)
            {
                var image = new Image();
                image.Source = await GetBitmapImageAsync(storageFile);
                Images.Add(image);
            }
        }

        public async Task<BitmapImage> GetBitmapImageAsync(StorageFile storageFile)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            IAsyncOperation<IRandomAccessStream> operation = storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await operation;
            bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
            return bitmapImage;
        }
```

then call all that in the OnNavigateTo event since the constructor can't be async

```
 protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            _imageList = new ImagesList();
            await _imageList.Initialize();
            foreach (var image in _imageList.Images)
            {
                Image img = new Image() { Source = image.Source };
                img.Width = img.Height = 200;
                img.Margin = new Thickness(20, 0, 20, 0);
                img.ImageFailed += image_ImageFailed;
                img.PointerEntered += img_PointerEntered;
                img.PointerExited += img_PointerExited;
                sp_MainStackPanel.Children.Add(img);
            }
        }
```

thanks again guys !

Comment: FWIW, you could change the 'await _imageList.Initialize()' to '_imageList.Initialize().Wait()' and then the code could be put in the ctor (since it would be running synchronously at that point and not rewritten).  If you're consuming an async API and don't want the caller to be async, just interacting with the returned Task normally (for instance, calling Wait()) is perfectly fine.  You only need to 'await' when you want the caller to also be async :)